# Flask-testing and selenium

Tags: python, selenium, flask

I am trying to get the tutorial here to work for flask-testing
https://flask-testing.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
specifically under 
Testing with LiveServer
If you want your tests done via Selenium or other headless browser like PhantomJS you can use the LiveServerTestCase:

```
import urllib2
from flask import Flask
from flask_testing import LiveServerTestCase

class MyTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        # Default port is 5000
        app.config['LIVESERVER_PORT'] = 8943
        return app

    def test_server_is_up_and_running(self):
        response = urllib2.urlopen(self.get_server_url())
        self.assertEqual(response.code, 200)
```

So I took their example and whenever I go to the page with selenium
it cannot find anything at that URL.  I tried printing out the URL and it is going to localhost on port 8943.  I googled around and couldn't find an example of someone using these two together.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.testing import LiveServerTestCase
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import unittest

class IntegrationTest(LiveServerTestCase):

    def create_app(self):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config['TESTING'] = True
        app.config['LIVESERVER_PORT'] = 8943
        return app

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = self.create_app()
        self.browser = webdriver.Firefox()
        self.browser.implicitly_wait(3)

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()

    def test_get_page(self):
        self.browser.get(self.get_server_url())
        self.assertNotIn("The requested URL was not found on the server.", self.browser.find_element_by_tag_name("body").text)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So I took their example and whenever I go to the page with selenium it
>   cannot find anything at that URL.

That test is just making sure the URL is reachable, i.e. that the returned *status code* is `200`. So it's working as expected as no/empty/default server response document is served on that URL.